# Seed method in migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know `Seed` method in configuration (migrations) is run when the database is created, right?

Can I use it to add some data to the database after it has been created?

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: besides the suggestion above, there's also another way to seed once your app starts